# SCCM PowerShell - Run Invoke-CMWmiQuery against a specific device collection?

Tags: powershell, sccm, sccm-2012-r2

I have the following WQL query:

```
select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_EndpointProtectionStatus on SMS_G_System_EndpointProtectionStatus.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_EndpointProtectionStatus.SignatureOlderThan7Days = 1
```

and I'm able to run it just fine by using

```
Invoke-CMWmiQuery -Query $WQL -Option Lazy
```

But is there a way I can limit this to to run against a particular device collection, like you can do in the SCCM console?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sccm/comments/bulwi9/_/eplcmpv), thanks to u/Johnny_Script:

> In order to limit your results to one collection, you need to add a `join SMS_FullCollectionMembership on SMS_FullCollectionMembership.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceID` into your query so that you have access to the collection data.  Then you need to add  `AND SMS_FullCollectionMembership.CollectionID = 'ABC0001'` to the end of the query to limit to a specific collection. Update the ABC0001 with the CollectionID of one of your CollectionIDs.  The final WQL statement should look like this:

```
SELECT SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID, SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType, SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name, SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier, SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup, SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client 
FROM SMS_R_System INNER JOIN SMS_G_System_EndpointProtectionStatus on SMS_G_System_EndpointProtectionStatus.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId JOIN SMS_FullCollectionMembership on SMS_FullCollectionMembership.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceID 
WHERE SMS_G_System_EndpointProtectionStatus.SignatureOlderThan7Days = 1 and SMS_FullCollectionMembership.CollectionID = 'ABC0001'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create an SCCM Query, then run it against a Device Collection. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/servers/manage/create-queries

Comment: Thanks, but that's NOT what I'm after. I'm looking for a way to do this within PowerShell using the Invoke-CMWmiQuery cmdlet.